# Call stored procedure from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In `SQLAlchemy`, what is the preferred way to call a stored database procedure? (including set arguments and receive exit status and outputted variables)

I've seen some examples that use `execute()` to execute a raw database string, but this could contain vendor specific syntax, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use execute and it can indeed contain vendor specific syntax.

You should also consider using `outparam`.

From [SQLAlchemy Docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.outparam) :

> `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.outparam(key, type_=None)` Create an ‘OUT’
>   parameter for usage in functions (stored procedures), for databases
>   which support them.
>
> The outparam can be used like a regular function parameter. The
>   “output” value will be available from the ResultProxy object via its
>   out_parameters attribute, which returns a dictionary containing the
>   values.

Here are some examples of using outparam: http://nullege.com/codes/search/sqlalchemy.sql.outparam