# How to call mysql stored proc using session in sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Based on the sqlalchemy it stated that:

> Its important to note that when using the SQLAlchemy ORM, these
>   objects are not generally accessed; instead, the Sessionobject is used
>   as the interface to the database.

So i have basic/simple model class, and i have another class with model class inside as attr. As follow:

```
Class Test (object):
    Model = ModelClass ()

    Def __init__(self):
        Pass

    Def call_proc (self, proc, param):
        # how?
        Pass
```

Questions:
How i call stored procedure from test class using session that i have in my model class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stored procedures with sqlAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563738/stored-procedures-with-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713430/call-stored-procedure-from-sqlalchemy has some insights. You could access DB-API level `callproc()` with a raw connection, if you need special handling: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#calling-stored-procedures.